# Swift UIKit how to masksToBounds for image view

Tags: swift, uiimage, uikit

My parent view has rounded corners on all sides and I would like the child image view to have rounded corners on the right-top and right-bottom to fit inside the parent view. [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410896-maskstobounds) says `masksToBounds` will solve this, but it does not work for me. As seen in the photo, the right side of the photo is not rounded on the right side. Let me know if you would like to see more of my code, thank you.

Here is my code:

```
            bottomViewThumbnailImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            bottomViewThumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
            bottomViewThumbnailImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                bottomViewThumbnailImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.topAnchor),
                bottomViewThumbnailImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.bottomAnchor),
                bottomViewThumbnailImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.trailingAnchor),
                bottomViewThumbnailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomViewThumbnailImageView.widthAnchor),
            ])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving this for your cell

```
layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

The property should be set for the imageView parent as it will flow to it's childs , setting it to the imageView itself has no effect

```
parentImg.clipsToBounds = true
```